# Creating a java application with a mainClass using Maven in Eclipse - 'Could not find the main class'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, executable

I'm trying to make an executable JAVA program. The source for this program has many different packages in the source folder. When I set the mainClass attribute in the pom.xml file below and run it as a maven build with the goal as 'package' it creates myapplication.jar. When I try to open it using

```
java -jar myapplication.jar
```

I get the message:

*'Could not find the main class: xxx.yyy.MainClass. Program will exit.*

Below is an excerpt from my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>xxx.yyy.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-a-jar</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and within MainClass.java (in the package xxx.yyy) I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // My Code
}
```

If i unpack the JAR file and look at the MANIFEST.MF file in the META-INF folder it contains the lines:

```
Main-Class: xxx.yyy.MainClass
Class-Path: aaa.jar bbb.jar ccc.jar
```

Where aaa.jar, bbb.jar and ccc.jar are the jar files that Maven has automatically downloaded as the project has dependency on them.
Both lines definitely end with a linefeed.

Also when I browse to the folder relative to the unpacked JAR xxx/yyy/MainClass.class is there!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you trying to run it? What's your classpath?

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm trying to run it using `java -jar myapplication.jar` when I get the error. The class path seems to be automatically generated by Maven in the MANIFEST.MF file in the format: `Class-Path: aaa.jar bbb.jar ccc.jar` - these are the jar files automatically downloaded by Maven as they were dependencies to the project.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit confused after lunch, but why are you executing the jar goal in the compile phase?

Comment: Is xxx.yyy.MainClass in your src/main/java or is it a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of this issue, because the error message doesn't fit, but note that the documentation of the jar option states:

"When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored."

So I doubt that

```
Class-Path: aaa.jar bbb.jar ccc.jar
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a maven project with your requirement. This is working fine.

I have uploaded here for your reference. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yuy9nfdj7mz4ec/testPackage.zip

This works just fine. Please note that i am using `maven-2.0.9`.